# How can I create a portabale version of VMware player

Tags: vmware

I would like to be able to create a portable version of VMware player 3. I have Googled it but haven't found much.

Comment: How about Portable VirtualBox?

Comment: What do you mean by "portable"?  It is already available on Windows, Linux, and ChromeOS

Comment: Portable meaning I dont have to install it and can run a virtual machine from a file or a usb drive. Basically want to thinstall VMware. but on top of that i want to convert a snapshot into this virtual machine :S

Comment: I dont think virtual box will run my VMware snapshot.

Comment: virtual box can read vmware's disk image without problem